# Values of non-elementary functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

Does the equation $\int e^{-x^2}dx =1$ have a solution in the set of real numbers?
It seems that it doesn't because if I take the derivative of both sides I get
$e^{-x^2}=0$ which obviously has no solutions except if we admit infinity as a solution.
I do not know much about non-elementary functions so I am not sure that my answer is correct, I am not even sure if I am asking the right question. (-:

Answer (score 7):

The indefinite integral $\int e^{-x^2}\;dx$ is a function, not a number.  It is not a constant function, in particular not the constant $1$.

However, there is a solution $a$ for
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-x^2}\;dx = 1
$$
Approximately $0.114$.
Now the equation is a number equal to a number.

---

Similar question: Is there a number $x$ so that $\int x^2 \;dx = 1$?  Same objection.  Now $\int x^2\;dx = \frac{x^3}{3}$, and there is, indeed, a number x so that $\frac{x^3}{3}= 1$.  Namely $x=3^{1/3}$ has that property.  But it is not legitimate to "differentiate" $\frac{x^3}{3}= 1$ and get $x^2 = 0$.